# ImportError: No module named misc.log

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I try to run the sample "scrapy" from [https://github.com/geekan/scrapy-examples](http://github.com/geekan/scrapy-examples)

When I try run project 'alexa' I get error:
[ImportError: misc.log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMlBn.jpg)

where should I look for 'misc.log'?

```
from alexa.items import *
from misc.log import *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[misc module](https://github.com/geekan/scrapy-examples/tree/master/misc) is also in the same directory as module `alexa`. You probably downloaded `alexa` alone and are trying to run it. Whereas this module depends on other modules. So what you can do is pull the whole project from github using `git clone https://github.com/geekan/scrapy-examples.git` and then run the examples so example modules can find the modules they need to run.

Answer (score 0):

The module `misc.log` is the [`log.py` in the folder `misc`](https://github.com/geekan/scrapy-examples/tree/master/misc) from geekan's repository.

Try running the alexa spider from the directory `scrapy-examples` so the script can locate the `misc.log` module. Of course, this is assuming that you have cloned the full repository in your computer.